# Matching strings in PowerShell

Tags: regex, powershell, string-matching

The **gist of this question** is:

So it seems that `if ($C -match $b.Name)` considers a *partial* match of a string a match? Is there a better way to force a *complete* [match] of a string?

I've got a directory that gets populated with a ton of .7z files. I need to clean this directory constantly. There is another script, that predates my employment here, that's currently working, but it's made up of 3000 lines and generates incorrect matches constantly and doesn't log what moved or what was deleted. Part of what makes it so big is that it has a ton of paths for where these files need to be moved to hard coded in it. Occasionally, these paths change and it's a pain in the butt to update.

So I've started making a much smaller script that has all these paths referenced in a CSV file. In addition to these paths, the CSV file also has known filenames recorded in it.

I'm trying to match the file names against the recorded names in my CSV file. It generally works, but sometimes I get incorrect matches.

Let's say I have two files that start similarly, Apple and Apple_Pie. Apple will match to Apple and move to the right directory, but Apple_Pie will first match to Apple and move to the wrong directory. Before the `$C` variable is cleared out it will match Apple_Pie to the right directory, but by that point Apple_Pie no longer exists in the original directory it needs to be moved from.

So it seems that `if ($C -match $b.Name)` considers a partial match of a string a match? Is there a better way to force a complete of a string?

I assume that I'm a bit off with my expectations of how `-match`should work.

The regex stuff I have here is to strip each file name of the date-time that gets added to the file name by another automated process. I use this to isolate the file name I want to match.

```
$Wild = "C:\Some\Folder\With\Files\"

$CSV = "C:\Another\Folder\Paths.csv"

$Content = gci $wild

$Reg1 = [regex] '_[0-9]{4}-[0-9]{2}-[0-9]{2}[A-Z]{1}[0-9]{2}_[0-9]{2}_[0-9]{2}'

$Reg2 = [regex] '[0-9]{4}-[0-9]{2}-[0-9]{2}[A-Z]{1}[0-9]{2}_[0-9]{2}_[0-9]{2}'

$Paths = import-csv -path $CSV -header Name, Path

foreach ($a in $content) {
    $c = $a.BaseName

    if ($c -match $reg1) {
        $c = $c -replace $regyear
    }
    elseif ($c -match $reg2) {
        $c = $c -replace $reg2
    }

    foreach ($b in $Paths) {

        if ($c -match $b.Name) {
            Do something
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I will start by pointing out that by default regex will be true if the pattern can be found anywhere in the string. If you want to find the string at certain positions within the string use `^` to indicate the beginning of the string and `$` to indicate the end of the string. To match the entire string use both.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think your main problem is that you are using "match".

It checks if the right string is ... part of the left one, not whether it's an actual match as you would expect.

```
$a = "Test"
$b = "Test_me"

$a -match $b
False

$b -match $a
True
```

I would replace `-match` with `-like`.

Comment: If you're going to recommend using `-like` instead of `-match`, please make it clear that (a) you won't be able to use your _regex_ with `-like` and (b) that the wildcard expressions that `-like` (exclusively) supports are far less powerful than regexes.
Also, I would clarify that `-match` doesn't treat the RHS as a _string_, but as a _regex_ - just to make it clear that `-match` doesn't perform _literal_ substring matching.

Answer (score 11):

**tl;dr**

- `-match` indeed makes the [regex](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Regular_Expressions) on the RHS (right-hand side) match *substrings* by default:

  ```bash
  'foo' -match 'o' # true
  ```
- However, you can *anchor* the regex with `^` to match the *start* of the input string, and/or `$` to match the *end*:

  ```bash
  'foo'  -match '^foo$' # true - full match
  'foot' -match '^foo$' # false
  ```

Read on for details and information about other string-matching operators.

---

Preface:

- PowerShell **string-[comparison operators](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_comparison_operators)** are **case-*insensitive* by default** (unlike the *string* operators, which use the [*invariant culture*](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.globalization.cultureinfo.invariantculture), the *regex* operators seem to use the *current* culture, though that difference rarely matters in regex operations).

  - You can opt into **case-*sensitive*** matching by using **prefix `c`**;
    e.g., `-cmatch` instead of `-match`.
- All comparison operators can be ***negated* with prefix `not`**; e.g., `-notmatch` negates `-match`.
- With a *single* string as the LHS, the comparison operators return `$True` or `$False`, but **with an *array* of strings  they act as *filters***; that is, they return the *subarray* of elements for which the comparison is true.

---

[EBGreen's](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1358/ebgreen) comment on the question provides the best explanation (lightly edited and emphasis added):

> [...] **by default, `-match` will return `$True` if the [RHS] pattern (regex) can be found *anywhere* in the string.** If you want to find the string at certain positions within the string, use `^` to indicate the beginning of the string and `$` to indicate the end of the string. To match the entire string, use both.

Applied to part of your code:

```bash
$Reg2 = '^[0-9]{4}-[0-9]{2}-[0-9]{2}[A-Z]{1}[0-9]{2}_[0-9]{2}_[0-9]{2}$'

# ...

$c -match $Reg2
```

Note the **`^`** at the start and the **`$`** at the end to ensure that the *entire* input string must match.

Also note that I've omitted the `[regex]` cast, as it isn't necessary, given that `-match` can accept *strings* directly.

On a related note, you can use assertion **`\b`** to modify substring matching so that matching only succeeds at *word boundaries* (where a word is defined as any nonempty run of letters, digits, and underscores); e.g. `'a10' -match 'a1'` is true, but `'a10' -match 'a1\b'` is not, because the `1` in the input string is not at the end of a word.

Note that using `-match` with a single string as the LHS (as opposed to an array) records the **details of the most recent match in the automatic `$Matches` variable**, which is a hash table whose `0` entry contains the entire match (the part of the input string that matched); if capture groups (subexpressions enclosed in `(...)`) were used in the regex - entry `1` contains what the 1st capture group captured, `2` what the 2nd one captured, and so on; *named* capture groups (e.g.,
`(?<foo>...)`) get entries by their name (e.g, `foo`).

Also, instead of a wordy `if` / `elseif` construct for matching multiple regexes in sequence, you can use the **[`switch` statement](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_switch)** with the `-regex` option:

Instead of:

```bash
if ($c -match $reg1) {
  $c = $c -replace $regyear 
}
elseif ($c -match $reg2) {
  $c = $c -replace $reg2 
}
```

you could write more cleanly:

```bash
switch -regex ($c) {
  $reg1 { $c = $c -replace $regyear; break }
  $reg2 { $c = $c -replace $reg2;    break }
  default { <# handles the case where nothing above matched #> }
}
```

`break` ensures that no further matching is performed.

- `switch`'s default matching (or with option `-exact`) works like the `-eq` operator (see below).
- You can also make it perform wildcard-expression matching - like the `-like` operator (see below) - with the
  `-wildcard` option.
- The `-casesensitive` option makes matching case-sensitive for any of the matching modes.
- If the input is an *array*, matching is performed on *each element*; note that `break` then *stop* processing of further elements, whereas `continue` instantly proceeds to the next element.

---

**Other methods of string matching in PowerShell**:

**`-like`** allows you to match strings based on [*wildcard expressions*](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_wildcards).

Simply put, `*` matches any run of characters, including *none*, `?` matches exactly *1* character, and `[...]` matches any one character in a specified *set* or *range* of characters.

Unlike `-match`, **`-like` always matches the *entire* string**, but note that wildcard expressions have fundamentally different syntax from regular expressions and are far less powerful - **you cannot use `-like` and `-match` interchangeably**.

Thus, to get *substring* matching, place a `*` o both ends of your expression; e.g.:

```bash
'ingot' -like '*go*'  # true
```

---

**`-eq`** compares *entire* strings, *literally* (except for case variations).

Note that **PowerShell has no literal substring-matching operator**, but you can (somewhat clumsily) emulate one with `-match` and [`[regex]::Escape()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.regularexpressions.regex.escape?view=netframework-4.7.2#System_Text_RegularExpressions_Regex_Escape_System_String_):

```bash
 'Cost: 7$.' -match [regex]::Escape('7$') # true
```

`[regex]::Escape()` escapes its argument so that its content is treated *literally* when interpreted as a *regex* (which the RHS of `-match` invariably is).

This is somewhat inefficient, as there is no good reason to use regexes to begin with.

Direct use of the [.NET `[string]` type's `.IndexOf()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.indexof?view=netframework-4.7.2#System_String_IndexOf_System_String_System_StringComparison_) method *is* an option, but is also nontrivial; the following is the equivalent of the previous command:

```bash
 'Cost: 7$.'.IndexOf('7$', [StringComparison]::InvariantCultureIgnoreCase) -ne -1 # true
```

Note the need to use `InvariantCultureIgnoreCase` to match PowerShell's default behavior, and the need to compare to `-1`, given that the *character index* of where the substring starts is returned.

On the flip side, this method gives you more control over how matching is performed, via the other members of the [`[System.StringComparison]`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.stringcomparison) enumeration.
If you're looking for case-*sensitive* substring matching based on the *current* culture, then you can simply rely on the default behavior of `.IndexOf()`; e.g.,
`'I am here.'.IndexOf('am') -ne -1 # true` vs.
`'I am here.'.IndexOf('AM') -ne -1 # false, because matching is case-sensitive`

---

Finally, note that the **[`Select-String` cmdlet](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/select-string)** performs string matching in the *pipeline*, and it supports both regexes (by default) and literal substring matching (with the `-SimpleMatch`) switch.

Unlike the comparison operators, `Select-Object` outputs a match-information object of type [`[Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.MatchInfo]`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.powershell.commands.matchinfo) for each matching input line that contains the original line plus metadata about the match.